# Limits of summations with different indices

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

In general, is it true that the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}$ is the same as the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_{i}$ for some sequence $x_{i}$?

Comment: Is the limit of $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$ the same?

Comment: Also, do you mean to write $x_i$?

Comment: yes they have the same limit

Comment: I did mean $x_{i}$

Comment: If both limits of the sums exist, either one may be said to be $\sum _{i=1}^{\infty} x_i.$ In that case both partial sums have the same limit by definition.